# Convert iso_8859_1 string to win1253 with delphi xe

Tags: delphi, encoding, delphi-xe

How can i do this conversion with delphi xe?
I've tried using libiconv2 but didn't worked.

Comment: What does "didn't worked" mean? I can't tell what went wrong for you from where I'm sitting.

Answer (score 5):

Using Dephi's built-in AnsiString charset support is best:

```
type
  // ISO-8859-1 and Windows-1252 are NOT the same, but
  // are commonly interchanged when they should not be!
  Latin1String = type AnsiString(28591);
  Windows1252String = type AnsiString(1252);
  GreekString = type AnsiString(1253);

procedure DoIt;
var
  S1: Latin1String;
  S2: Windows1252String;
  S3: GreekString;
begin
  S1 := '...'; // auto-converts to ISO-8859-1
  S2 := S1; // auto-converts from ISO-8859-1 to Unicode to Windows-1252
  S3 := S1; // auto-converts from ISO-8859-1 to Unicode to Greek
end;
```

Comment: This is indeed the easiest way of doing the conversion since Delphi 2009. You could use manual conversion via Windows API calls with previous version of Delphi: MultiByteToWideChar then WideCharToMultiByte - it's always better to call Windows API than libiconv2 which is NOT a standard under Windows!

Comment: The Win32 API only supports charsets whose codepages are installed (.NET has some built-in support for additional charsets, but there are many charsets used in the world).  libiconv is not limited by that restriction, and is available for install on Windows.